# Convergence Random Series a.e implies Convergence Squared Sequence

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

My question is the following. Let's say that I have a random series $\sum_n \pm X_n$, that is it converges a.e for all possible choices of $+1 \text{ and } -1$, then how can I show that $\sum_n X_n^2$ converges a.e?

My first idea was to make a Bernoulli like random variable and apply Fubini with the product measure. That is for a random variables $Y_n$ with $\mathbb{P}(Y_n = 1) = p = 1-\mathbb{P}(Y_n = -1)$ defining the random variable $Z_n = X_nY_n$, being $Y$ and $X$ independent we could have by Fubini.

$$\int X_nY_n d(F_x \times F_y) = \int \left( \int X_nY_n dF_y\right) dF_x = \int X_n\cdot(-1+2p) dF_x = \mathbb{E}[X_n](-1+2p)$$
The expected value can be guaranteed, because it is bounded by the series $\sum_n \pm X_n$ that converges almost everywhere, thus there is some series that dominates $X_n$(I am not certain about this fact). But I am stuck here. I don't have any idea how to proceed, any suggestions?

Comment: If $|X_n|=1$ for all $n$, then the sum of the squares will not converge!

Comment: So, is the question wrong? Because this is exercise 5.3.10 from Chung.

Comment: @herbsteinberg That doesn't appear to satisfy the hypothesis that $\sum_n \pm X_n$ converges for all possible choices of signs, assuming I am reading it correctly.  Incidentally, I find that choice of notation very confusing.  I would phrase it as "$\sum_n \epsilon_n X_n$ converges a.e. for any sequence $(\epsilon_n) \in \{-1,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$."

Comment: Yes, this is what is meant with the $\epsilon$. I am just using the notation of Chung.

Comment: @JohannMartens Right, I was just saying Chung's notation was confusing.  For this problem, I would give the hint of just proving it if $X_n$ is a sequence of real numbers.  I don't think there is anything probabilistic going on here.